# Public Wi-Fi connection difficulty

Tags: wifi, iphone, cellular-data

My iPhone 5 will not connect to some public Wi-Fi connections. I have found that if I turn off cellular data it will usually connect. It is as if the two are competing. Anyone know why this happens or how to fix?

Comment: It will do what you asked. As long both are on it will choose the better connection. The only way around it is to turn off cellular data to force it to use WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

If the iPhone decides that the cellular data connection will provide a better connection quality, it will choose that connection over a poor Wi-Fi connection. However, given no other choice (because you've turned off cellular data) the iPhone will attempt to maintain the poor connection over Wi-Fi.

There is no way around this other than to improve the Wi-Fi connection or to disable cellular data manually.